# How to iterate over a char pointer array returned by a function in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I create a function that creates a 28 array from random chars from a-z.
When I try to iterate over the pointer array from `main` I get the wrong values.

**What do I'm missing?**

I know array are passed by reference to function, does are returned by reference too?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#define MAX 28

// Generate random char array with a-z values
char* generateRandomString(int length) {
    char random[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Minimun a ascii = 97
        // Maximun z ascii = 122
        srand(int(time(NULL))); // Timestamp seed generator
        int randomInt = 97 + (rand() % 25);
        char randomChar = randomInt;
        random[i] = randomChar;
    }
    return random;
}

int main() {
    char* random = generateRandomString(MAX);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        std::cout << random[i] << std::endl; // (*random)[i] Does not work neither
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You *cannot* declare a local array and return its address like that.  The memory becomes invalid when the function goes out of scope.  You have (at least) two choices: 1) "new" the array, or 2) allocate the buffer *outside* of the function, and pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: Side note:  variable-length arrays are not valid c++.  Return a std:string instead.

Comment: Your code returns a pointer by value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope before the caller can use it.  Just use `std::string` instead.

And don't call `srand()` multiple times, call it only once.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1: Even better, don't use `srand()` at all, use a C++ random number generator from the [`<random>` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) instead.</sup>

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#define MAX 28

// Generate random char array with a-z values
std::string generateRandomString(int length) {
    std::string random;
    random.resize(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Minimun a ascii = 97
        // Maximun z ascii = 122
        int randomInt = 97 + (rand() % 25);
        char randomChar = randomInt;
        random[i] = randomChar;
    }
    return random;
}

int main() {
    srand(int(time(NULL))); // Timestamp seed generator

    std::string random = generateRandomString(MAX);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        std::cout << random[i] << std::endl; // (*random)[i] Does not work neither
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to cpp so I really appreciate your suggestions!!

Answer (score 1):

> ```cpp
> char random[length];
> ```

^^This^^ array lives on the stack. When `generateRandomString()` returns, it returns the address of a variable that is about to die. To keep that memory alive, you'd need to allocate it dynamically:

```cpp
char* generateRandomString(int length) {
    char* random = new char[length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Minimun a ascii = 97
        // Maximun z ascii = 122
        srand(int(time(NULL))); // Timestamp seed generator
        int randomInt = 97 + (rand() % 25);
        char randomChar = randomInt;
        random[i] = randomChar;
    }
    random[length] = 0; //< null terminate string
    return random;
}
```

Just remember you'll need to delete the memory once you've finished using it!

```cpp
char* random = generateRandomString(MAX);
...
delete[] random;
```

Alternatively, use `std::string`:

```cpp
std::string generateRandomString(int length) {
    std::string random(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Minimun a ascii = 97
        // Maximun z ascii = 122
        srand(int(time(NULL))); // Timestamp seed generator
        int randomInt = 97 + (rand() % 25);
        char randomChar = randomInt;
        random[i] = randomChar;
    }
    return random;
}
```

```cpp
std::string random = generateRandomString(MAX);
...
```

Comment: Popping my head in here to point out that the `+ 1` in `char* random = new char[length + 1];` and the `random[length] = 0; //< null terminate string` are utterly freaking important if you are going to use `char` arrays to hold strings.

Answer (score 0):

The function `generateRandomString` returns pointer to the first element of a local array.

```
char* generateRandomString(int length) {
    char random[length];

    //...
    return random;
}
```

After exiting the function the array will not be alive. Its memory can be overwritten. So the pointer will be invalid. As a result the program has undefined behavior.

Instead of the character array you can use the standard class `std::string`. It is better than to "manually" dynamically allocate a character array.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how your original program can be updated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

std::string generateRandomString( size_t length ) 
{
    std::string s( length, ' ' );

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( auto &c : s )
    {
        c = 'a' + std::rand() % ( 'z' - 'a' + 1 );
    }

    return s;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t MAX = 28;

    std::string s = generateRandomString( MAX );

    for ( const auto &c : s ) std::cout << c;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Its output might look for example like

```
xzefeqsnthhgmfunychcklplccjv
```

If you want to learn how to deal with dynamically allocated arrays then the program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

char * generateRandomString( size_t length ) 
{
    char *s = new char[length + 1];

    s[length] = '\0';

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++  )
    {
        s[i] = 'a' + std::rand() % ( 'z' - 'a' + 1 );
    }

    return s;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t MAX = 28;

    char *s = generateRandomString( MAX );

    std::cout << s << '\n';

    delete [] s;
}
```

Pay attention to that it is not a good idea to use such magic numbers as 97. They make the code unclear. And there is no usually need to define constants in a C++ using the #define directive. Instead use C++ declarations of constants.